# Scrolling issues with Facebook Requests dialog

Tags: facebook, iframe, scroll, facebook-iframe

I am trying to call new [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) from an iframe facebook application by clicking a button located at the bottom of a page (you need to scroll to get there).

This is what happens when you click the button:

- Temporary dialog with a progress bar is displayed in the middle of visible screen
- Page is getting automatically scrolled to the top
- Actual dialog appears in place of that temp loading dialog at the bottom of the page, so it is not visible

Is there a way to make it either not scroll to the top automatically or at least display the final dialog at the top as well so it can be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug:  http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15440